# Can not submit for app store review because of build

Tags: ios, build

I already did a build and distributed the app with xCode. My bundle id is the same as my app project but I keep getting an error when submitting for review
[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Woodstock There are one or more errors on the page. I think that the build is not comming out, its the first time I publish an app and I am not sure if the build is supposed to show on that section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw that I have a appstore email saying the following:

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Wey" 1.1 (1). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'org.Quarentino.WeNews'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.

It means that I need to add:

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

to my info.plist